# Extension Method for DevExpress GridView Columns

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, devexpress, extension-methods

How can I extend DevExpress GridView Columns. It doesn't appear that DevExpress is able to follow DataAnnotations Display.

Here is what I put together to achieve this behavior:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static void AddModelToGrid<T>(
        this MVCxGridViewColumnCollection devExpCollection, 
        List<T> model)
    {
        model.ForEach((obj) =>
        {
            obj.GetType().GetProperties().ToList().ForEach((prop) =>
            {
                var displayName = 
                    (DisplayAttribute)prop.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(DisplayAttribute));
                string name = null;
                if (displayName != null)
                {
                    name = displayName.Name;
                }
                else
                {
                    name = prop.Name;
                }

                devExpCollection.Add(prop.Name, name);
            });
        });
    }
}
```

The idea was to use it like this.

```
@using MyApp.Models

@{
    var grid = Html.DevExpress().GridView(settings =>
    {
        settings.Name = "GridView";
        settings.CallbackRouteValues = new { Controller = "Home", Action = "GridViewPartial" };

        settings.KeyFieldName = "ID";

        settings.SettingsPager.Visible = true;
        settings.Settings.ShowGroupPanel = true;
        settings.Settings.ShowFilterRow = true;
        settings.SettingsBehavior.AllowSelectByRowClick = true;

        /* This doesn't work */
        settings.Columns.AddModelToGrid<MyObject>(settings.Columns);

    });
    if (ViewData["EditError"] != null)
    {
        grid.SetEditErrorText((string)ViewData["EditError"]);
    }
}
@grid.Bind(Model).GetHtml()
```

How can I achieve this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static void AddModelToGrid<T>(
        this MVCxGridViewColumnCollection devExpCollection)
    {
        // you just need the T parameter, not a list
        typeof(T).GetProperties().ToList().ForEach((prop) =>
        {
            DisplayAttribute displayName = null; 

            var attributes = prop.GetCustomAttributes(true);

            foreach (var attribute in attributes)
            {
                if (attribute is DisplayAttribute)
                {
                    displayName = (DisplayAttribute)attribute;
                }
            }

            string name = null;
            if (displayName != null)
            {
                name = displayName.Name;
            }
            else
            {
                name = prop.Name;
            }

            devExpCollection.Add(prop.Name, name);
        });
    }
}
```

Or less verbose

```
typeof(T).GetProperties().ToList().ForEach((prop) =>
{                
    var attributes = prop.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayAttribute), true);
    string name = attributes.Length > 0 ? ((DisplayAttribute)attributes[0]).Name : prop.Name;
    devExpCollection.Add(prop.Name, name);
});
```

Then in the view

```
settings.Columns.AddModelToGrid<YourType>();
```

Comment: Excellent, I still don't get why the other way didn't work. The error didn't say anything about the Model being the issue.

Comment: Here you just say to the GridView what properties it has to display (you bind it to a type), than only when you call `@grid.Bind(Model).GetHtml()` you pass the actual Model.